# Converting from <Datatype1>[] to <Datatype2>[]

Tags: java

Wondering if it would be plausible to convert from a list of datatypes without going through the trouble of looping through the entire list.

I.e:`b = {"1", "2"}; 
Integer[] a = (Integer[]) b; //not actually runnable`

Not really necessary, but it would be nice.

Comment: You can probably do it in a one-liner in Java 8, but a loop will have to be there (even if it's hidden from you by methods), because the base types are not compatible so there is actually work to be done converting each value - it's not merely a reference cast.

Comment: So the type is not cast by a pointer? If it was, it should be possible to just change the pointer to the array.

Comment: No, the data is totally different. It's not polymorphic, therefore it's not just a type cast. E.g. for `"14"` You need to transfer the characters `'1'` and `'4'` into the number 14. That doesn't happen by magic.

Comment: Would expect it to be stored by ('value', pointer to next value). If we know where the value stops, then it shouldn't be a problem as long as we only have single digits. Assuming the values represent the same in both types?

Comment: In Java, you can't do that. A String is an object and it consists not only of one or more bytes for the character, it is a object with fields, and can't be accessed in such a low-level way.

Comment: Not in Java, and not in any other language that stores characters encoded in ASCII, Unicode, etc., in units that are less than the width of an integer. In Java the character`'1'` is internally the the two-byte, unsigned value *48*. It's not the four-byte, twos-complement value *1*.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8, you can do

```
Integer[] integerArray = 
    Stream.of(stringArray)
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

If you want an int-Array, you can do:

```
int[] intArray = 
Stream.of(stringArray)
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .toArray();
```

`Stream.of()` creates a stream from the array.
map maps every element of the stream to an Integer using `Integer::parseInt`. Using `mapToInt`, you can create an `Intstream`, which is a specialization of streams for integer primitives. `Integer[]::new` is a method reference to an array constructor.

This assumes all elements of the array are parseable, if not it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Integer.parseInt(String str)` method from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: You don't want to loop over the list, won't you? Because the op explicitly asked for solution that don't.